# Why is watch method in Vue.js being triggered when prop was not changed?

Tags: vue.js

I understand that when a property/data being watched is changed/re-assigned, then the watch method for that property/data is triggered.

However, in this code snippet, the watch method for initTasks is triggered although initTasks is not changed/touched (or so it seems).

This code snippet is supposed to increment the "estimate" every time a task is added. However, estimate is not incremented because estimate is overridden by initTask's watch method every time.

https://jsfiddle.net/akosipax/1qtLfyn4/43/

```js
Vue.component('customcomponent', {
 props: ['initTasks', 'initEstimate'],
  data()  {
   return {
     tasks: [],
      estimate: 0,
    }
  },
  
  template: `
   <div>
     <ul>
       <li v-for="(task, index) in tasks" :key="index">
          {{task.text}}
        </li>
      </ul>
      <p>It will take you {{estimate}} hours to do all of these!</p>
      <button @click="addTask">Add task</button>
   </div>
  `,
  
  methods: {
   initialize() {
      this.tasks = this.initTasks;
      this.estimate = this.initEstimate;
    },
    
    addTask() {
     Vue.set(this.tasks, this.tasks.length, {
       text: "Do this new task"
      });
      
      this.estimate++;
    }
  },
  
  watch: {
   initTasks: function(oldval, newval) {
     console.log('watch for initTasks triggered!');
      this.initialize();
    }
  },
  
  mounted() {
   console.log('mounted() triggered!')
   this.initialize();
  },
  
  created() {
   console.log('created() triggered!')
  },
  
  updated() {
    console.log('updated() triggered!')
  },
  
  destroyed() {
    console.log('updated() triggered!')
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    tasks: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript"},
      { text: "Learn Vue"},
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle"},
      { text: "Build something awesome"}
    ],
    estimate: 5
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <customcomponent :init-tasks="tasks" :init-estimate="estimate"></customcomponent>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your initialize method to:

```
    initialize() {
      this.tasks = this.initTasks.slice();
      this.estimate = this.initEstimate;
    }
```

Everything will work. I think the watcher is being triggered because when you change the tasks array the initTasks is also changed because arrays are [Mutable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Mutable).

If you are using es2015 and beyond you can do:

`this.tasks = ...[this.initTasks];` **OR**

`this.tasks = Array.from(this.initTasks);`